# UseState inside routed functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-props, setstate

I'm creating my first app with react-router and was having some trouble with an invalid hook error. I did manage to fix the error, but I don't really understand why this fixed it. So, in my App component I had a Switch with the following Route:

```
   <Route 
      path="/signin" 
      exact 
      render={SignIn}
   />
```

Now lets suppose the SignIn component looked like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SignIn = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState('test');

  return (
    <main>
      {test}
    </main>
  )
}

export default SignIn;
```

With this set-up I kept getting an invalid hooks error, which only went away when I changed the Route in the App component to this:

```
<Route 
  path="/signin" 
  exact 
  render={(props) => <SignIn {...props}/>}
/>
```

Now this had solved the problem and the invalid hook problem went away, but why? I am not actually using any props in the SingIn component, at least not at the moment. Which of the React Hook Rules am I breaking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `SignIn` is a component, you can do it like this:

```
<Route 
     path="/signin" 
     exact 
     component={SignIn}
/>
```

The `render` syntax is when you want to pass some additional props

Comment: That also makes it work, thank you. But I still do not understand why the render method works as long as you do not use hooks.

Comment: Because `render` expects a function, not a component

Comment: `SignIn` is a component, while `(props) => <SignIn {...props}/>` is a function

Comment: There is nothing to understand here, if you use the wrong parameter, of course you will get an error

Comment: Ok, so I understand that the fact that the render={SingIn} works and actually renders the component if I remove the hook is basically an unexpected byproduct of incorrect type usage.